# Solution .Net com Membership não conecta a base oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, oracle11g

Estou tentando executar um projeto no meu computador mas ele acusa erro na string:

> OracleConnection.ConnectionString é inválido

O mesmo projeto funciona normalmente no computador onde ele foi iniciado.
A versão do oracle em ambos computadores é 11g. Removi todo oracle da minha máquina e reinstalei, assim como o ODAC 4.

A mesma string que estou usando no WebConfig está no TNSNames do oracle e me conecto com a base normalmente.

Fiz a conexão com a mesma base no visual studio usando Oracle OLE DB, conexão também funcionou.

Tenho outra aplicação que conecta com o mesmo banco e funciona, a única diferença é que essa outra aplicação não tem membership.
Minha String de conexão no Webconfig:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="Oracle" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" connectionString="User ID=User;Password=MinhaSenha;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.200)(PORT = 1570)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = MyServiceName.Exemplo.com)));Connection Timeout=14400;Max Pool Size=900;" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

Algumas tentativa já realizadas:

- No ASP.Net Configuration, em providers, habilitei a opção OracleMembershipProvider tanto para Membership Provider quanto Role
  Provider.
- No ASP.Net Configuration, em security, não consigo fazer alterações
  devido ao erro "OracleConnection.ConnectionString é inválido".
- Comentei a linha onde aponta o erro, mas sempre que o BD é chamado
  ocorre o mesmo erro em outra linha com membership.
- Refiz a referência para o Oracle.DataClient com rebuild da solution.

Aparentemente as configurações das duas máquinas estão iguais: VS2012 e Oracle 11g com ODDAC versão 4.112.3.0.

Cheguei a desconfiar de algo do Warning abaixo, mas pesquisando na web não encontrei nada relacionado:

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project
>   being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference
>   "Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86", "x86".
>   This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the
>   targeted processor architecture of your project through the
>   Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures
>   between your project and references, or take a dependency on
>   references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted
>   processor architecture of your project.

Alguém já passou por algo parecido e poderia ajudar a resolver esse problema? Alguns colegas falaram que é chato rodar membership no oracle, realmente da tanto problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem [várias(1)](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2425852?tstart=0) [inconsistências(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750172/entity-framework-oracle-cannot-insert-varchar2-1-999-characters) e [instabilidades(3)](https://community.oracle.com/message/10195157) documentadas relativas à utilização do ODP.NET não gerenciado que podem depender, entre outros fatores, da versão do cliente e do assembly instalados.

A solução recomendada envolve utilizar o pacote nuget `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`, que é considerado mais estável.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/

As diferenças entre os dois estão listadas [neste guia da Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/intro004.htm#ODPNT8146).

[Este post no StackOverflow original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583289/oracle-odp-net-managed-vs-unmanaged-driver) lista os benefícios. Em tradução livre:

- Menos arquivos (1 dll na maioria dos casos, 2 no máximo)
- Menor consumo de espaço ( 10 MB ao invés de 200 MB)
- Publicação lado-a-lado mais fácil
- Mesmo assembly para versões 32 e 64 bits (exceto quando usando MTS)

Comment: Já estou lendo sobre as diferenças, vou trocar no projeto e ver se resolve o caso e marco como resposta. Obrigado!

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann boa sorte!

Comment: Encontrei o erro no meu web config, mas preferi usar sua solução devidos as vantagens dela. O erro no meu web.config estava no roleManager. Precisava adicionar o elemento filho <provider>. Segue link para mais informações: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms164660(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann Ah, confesso que não me ocorreu verificar a presença do `<provider>`. De qualquer maneira fico feliz que tenha encontrado uma solução adequada!